# How does one represent a range like $[a,b]$ if the ^range^ is exactly $1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just as the title suggests, I'm wondering how one represent a range like $[a,b]$ if the ^range^ is exactly $1$? I ask because for the colleciton $\mathscr{B}=\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1,1+\frac{1}{n}\end{bmatrix}:n\in \mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}=\{[1,2],[1,\frac{3}{2}],[1,\frac{3}{3}],\dots\}$
$$\bigcap_{B\in \mathscr{B}} B=\underbrace{???}_{\text{How do I represent this as a set?}}$$

Comment: But $\bigcup_{B\in \mathscr{B}} B$ contains more points than just $1$.  Perhaps you're thinking of the intersection, not the union?

Comment: Yes, I mean $\bigcap$...

Comment: So the open set $(1,1+1/n)$ would have $(1,2)$ and $\varnothing$, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you may have meant to ask about the intersection, not the union:

$$\bigcup\mathscr{B}=[1,2]\;,$$

and

$$\bigcap\mathscr{B}=\{1\}\;.$$

(You *can* write $[1,1]$ for $\{1\}$, but it tends to be a little confusing and is usually better avoided.)

Comment: So for the union would I not write $\{[1,2]\}$?

Comment: Pedantry... I know... I'm sorry, but I just want to know what the custom is should such a custom exist.

Comment: Wow! Try to say "should such a custom" three times fast. `:-)`

Comment: @Loie: No, the union is $[1,2]$, not $\{[1,2]\}$. The union consists of everything that belongs to at least one of the sets $[1,2],\left[1,\frac32\right],\ldots$; those things are precisely the real numbers in $[1,2]$, and there are a *lot* of them! $\{[1,2]\}$, on the other hand, is a set that has only *one* member, and it isn’t a real number at all: it’s the set $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you meant to denote the intersection of all $B \in \mathscr B$, then we have: $$\bigcap \mathscr B = \{1\},$$

which denotes the set consisting of exactly one point (i.e., a singleton). That's the most straightforward representation of the set you refer to $(\text{How do I represent this as a set?})$

Comment: $\huge{+}\Large{+}$+

Comment: @amWhy: Clean and to the point! +1

Answer (score 1):

As you are already notified by others, you might need the intersection of that family of sets which is a singleton set and there's no problem if you write it as an interval. In that case $a=b$, that's all. Notice that while defining intervals, we don't restrict the values taken by a and b by saying $a<b$ or things like that. If $a>b$, our interval defines just the empty set! No problem at all..``